# where does 'pkg-config' takes its information from?

Tags: linux, debian

where does 'pkg-config' takes its information from?

What files do I need when building a .deb package ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config

> pkg-config retrieves information about
>   packages from special metadata files.
>   These files are named after the
>   package, with the extension .pc. By
>   default, pkg-config looks in the
>   directory prefix/lib/pkgconfig for
>   these files; it will also look in the
>   colon-separated (on Windows,
>   semicolon-separated) list of
>   directories specified by the
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 9):

Following the manual (at least in my version of pc-config), the search path for the relevant *.pc-files will be displayed with the command:

```
pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
```

So, if I want to compile something e.g. with libsoup and don't know the version number (let's say 2.4) of libsoup installed, I was successfull writing:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs $(grep -l 'Cflags.*libsoup' $(find $(pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config|tr ':' ' ') -name "*.pc" 2>/dev/null)|tail -n1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the info whilst poking around: I did

> pkg-config --debug dbus-1

and I got:

> /usr/lib/pkginfo
>
> /usr/share/pkgconfig

a lot of times... so I guess I just need to drop '.pc.' files in those directories when I am building a .deb package.